# Rename and add types when destructuring an object

Tags: typescript

This

```
payload = { 
  logo: // type is Blob
  name: // type is string
}

function save({ logo, name }) {
 //
}
```

when calling the save with payload

```
save(payload)
```

I need to rename 'logo' into 'file' and need to define types for both fields, is it possible to rename and adding types in the same time when destructuring an object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with normal Javascript destructuring, to put into a new variable name, put a colon after the property you want to rename, with the new identifier on the right:

```
logo: file
```

Then you need to set the type of the whole object being passed, which is done by putting `:` after the argument:

```
function save({ logo: file, name }: { logo: Blob; name: string; }) {
```

It looks a bit repetitive, but I don't think there's a better way.

Comment: I thought it is possible to pass types for each destructured fields. I got it now. Thanks